# Interacting with iESS process from Emacs (evaluate)

Tags: r, emacs, process, ess

Is there anyway to send text to an iESS buffer which does not need to follow `(inferior-ess-send-input)`?

I basically do this:

```
(process-send-string "R" "mycommand()")
(select-window (get-buffer-window "*R*"))
(inferior-ess-send-input)
```

The concern is that like this it ends up with some added characters to that buffer, looking like this:

```
> 
>
```

Is there a cleaner way to have Emacs interact with the ESS/R process?

I want to use this to create some parallel processing within R being handled by Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

">" is the prompt and is printed by R each time you send something to the process. If you want to avoid that use `ess-command` instead. You can supply custom buffer for the output.

Parallel processing with emacs is probably not a good idea. Better use R to span multiple R subprocesses.